# thread safe nsdictionary

Tags: cocoa, nsdictionary

I have an nsdictionary that gets read from A LOT and at some points concurrently written to A LOT.

To help make it thread safe when iterating it, I copy it, iterate the copy, and add to the original.

Sometimes, another thread is copying it while it is being added to. Is there a better way to make it thread safe?

Answer (score 1):

If you have changes you want to make to an `NSMutableDictionary` and need the operations to be done in a thread-safe manner, the simplest way is to wrap all accesses on that object with the `@synchronized` statement, which tells the compiler to lock access to the object in a thread-safe, exception-safe fashion:

```
@synchronized (myDictionary) {
    [myDictionary setObject: ... forKey: ...];
    [myDictionary removeObjectForKey: ...];
}
```

There are higher-performance alternatives to `@synchronized`, but that should only be a concern if you've profiled your code and see synchronization is an issue.

Comment: Nothing about NSMutableDictionary is thread safe except reading only (i.e., treating it exactly the same as an immutable NSDictionary and only writing to it at initialization).

Comment: Ah, crap, you're right. I'd thought the `__Mutable____` subclasses had been made thread-safe. Editing my answer.

Comment: +1 and please remove the comments, they now make no sense without looking at the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

one of many approaches:

create a class which contains an appropriate lock and a dictionary (specifically, i use c++ templates which serve as containers). then wrap the interface as necessary. i've done this for many CF/NS types. it's about as fast as is reasonable. since you're dealing with collections, you have several considerations (e.g, is the lock held while the contents mutate?)