# @synchronized vs GCD dispatch_barrier_async

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I've begun controlling queues for the first time and feel like I have a good handle on how to use them and kudos to Apple for making them quite straightforward to use.

What I encountered, however, is the challenge of multiple threads reading and writing to the same objects. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920584/mutating-array-while-reading-not-enumerating) I got [this fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11921122/768472), and it leaves me asking for some confirmation from everyone to make sure I understand the pros and cons of `@synchronized` vs `GCD dispatch_barrier_async`.

This is the way I see it:

```
 @synchronized
```

**PRO**: You can wrap any object in `@synchronized` as long as you have access/pointer to it, making it easy for shared data models to be safely handled from different objects in the program

**PRO**: Supported by iOS 4 (and maybe earlier)

```
 `dispatch_barrier_async` with custom DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT
```

**PRO**: Is faster than @synchronized

**CON**: DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT only available in iOS 5 (as discussed [here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html)), so not available for supporting iOS 4

**CON**: Not as easy to use when controlling read/write on an object from many other objects, since queues are most easily available only to the object that creates them (without some work to go around this limitation)

**In summary,** the best tool depends on the needs of the program, in consideration of the above.

If anyone has something to add or point out, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, a few things to point out:

1) When you use @synchronized, it pulls in the WHOLE exception framework for iOS (or OSX) for an app. I know of this on OSX and it has a performance impact there, cannot say for sure on iOS but would expect the same. That said, this is using a sledgehammer to drive in a nail - that capability was around way before other options were available. I personally avoid its use like the plague, and have ported other open source frameworks to use dispatch semaphores (I thank Mike Ash (again) for that!)

2) Your comment about "DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT" is a red herring of sort - since iOS 4 the system has given you 3 concurrent queues so you really are pushing the envelope if you need to define your own. With dispatch, you have async and sync, serial and concurrent, groups that you can wait on, dispatch after. There is such a richness here how could you even think of 1). The more you use blocks the more you will use them!

EDIT: I used custom concurrent queues in my iOS 4.3 app, along with all the Mike Ash barrier techniques. The queue.h file shows it as available:

```
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_4_0)
DISPATCH_EXPORT DISPATCH_CONST DISPATCH_WARN_RESULT DISPATCH_NOTHROW
dispatch_queue_t
dispatch_get_global_queue(dispatch_queue_priority_t priority, unsigned long flags);

/*!
 * @const DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL
 * @discussion A dispatch queue that invokes blocks serially in FIFO order.
 */
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL NULL

/*!
 * @const DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT
 * @discussion A dispatch queue that may invoke blocks concurrently and supports
 * barrier blocks submitted with the dispatch barrier API.
 */
#define DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT (&_dispatch_queue_attr_concurrent)
```

Comment: Your point 2) does not apply to dispatch_barrier, since you cannot use this on a global queue, only a custom concurrent queue. For thread safe read/write using GCD mechanism, you need a custom concurrent queue. Described here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html

Comment: I edited my answer - I used the Mike Ash techniques in my iOS 4.3 app so I know for sure the barriers where there for concurrent queues.

Comment: this is interesting, in another question of mine and on Ash's site as well, it was mutually agreed by all that custom concurrent queues are only available in iOS 5 and later; you are suggesting otherwise. global concurrent queues have always been available, but everyone is under the impression that custom concurrent queues are a very recent addition to iOS (though have been in OS X previously)

Comment: further investigation leads me to see from multiple sources that custom concurrent queues were made available on Lion, 10.7, not 10.6 as suggested by this header file. I suspect all the sources are correct on this. Are you sure you were not using barriers on global queues in your app? Doing so would appear to work, but in reality they would simply be normal async and sync dispatches, since the OS does not allow barriers on the global queues, but does allow the syntax. since you suggested that custom concurrent queues were pushing the envelope, perhaps you are not actually using them?

Comment: I am like 100% sure. Again, I look in BOTH the documentation and the header file - just posting the header file - note 4.3: "#ifdef __BLOCKS__
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_3)
DISPATCH_EXPORT DISPATCH_NONNULL_ALL DISPATCH_NOTHROW
void
dispatch_barrier_async(dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block);
#endif

Comment: One last comment - if you look at Mike Ash's page again, at the comments at the bottom, you will see several people including me state the barrier functionality is in 4.3: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-14-whats-new-in-gcd.html

Comment: Your comment on that page is with regards to `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` not barriers

Comment: I'll stop after this comment - my comment DID mention barriers and I was using them with 4.3, tested on my phone, submitted to the store, etc etc. Note the other person who commented (with no contradiction!): "Steven Fusco at 2011-10-17 18:10:36:
You can get to priority background and the new barrier API in iOS 4.3, no need to wait for 5. It's marked __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_3) 
 in the header"

Comment: Thanks David. It would seem there has been some widespread confusion on the availability of these features in different OS versions.

Comment: Some data points looking at the SDKs I have on this machine: In the OS X 10.6 SDK with Xcode 3.2.6, it's marked: __MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_NA ), in the iOS 4.3 SDK in the same Xcode it's marked: __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_4_0).  In Xcode 4.6.3: Mac OS X 10.8 SDK has __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_4_0), 10.7 SDK has: __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_4_0), and iOS 6.1 SDK has: __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_4_0).                  So I'm curious which SDK someone is seeing that (__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3) value....